# How to filter a one-to-many getter?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm making minor amendments to a Symfony 1.4 system. I am not very familiar with Symfony.

The Doctrine model is already set up with a one-to-many getter, but I need to add a filter.  for example, getting Bars from a Foo with `Foo->getBars()`, I want to pass a parameter to getBars to filter only X type of Bar, i.e. `Foo->getBars('X');`

The base class `BaseFoo` already has this in place in the `setUp` method

```
$this->hasMany('Foo_Bars as Bars', array(
    'local'   => 'foo_id',
    'foreign' => 'foo_id'
));
```

Apologies for the rather abstract example, but the real object names would possibly make less sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new query for that ....

In the `/lib/model/doctrine/foo.class.php` file create a new function :

```
public function getBarsWithX($x)
{
   return Doctrine_Core::getTable('Foo')->createQuery('f')
       ->innerjoin('f.Bar b')
       ->where('f.id = ?',self::_get('id'))
       ->andWhere('b.x = ?',$x)            // Change this line to match the field name
       ->execute();
}
```

That will return the Doctrine Hydrated object you require... its called by

`Foo->getBarsWithX('x);`

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

By the time you call `$foo->getBars()`, $foo is already hydrated. At that point, you could override the `public function getBars()`.

However, why don't you narrow down your result set in the first place by modifying your query instead?

Comment: P.S.: 2 hours without an answer! That's disappointing indeed! ;)

Comment: Thanks, although I don't quite follow your point about the query. Are you suggesting that my original `$model->getFoos()` query can be altered to only join Bars onto Foos that are of type X?